# JQuery Mobile simpledialog clears my dynamic data from the page

Tags: jquery-mobile

JQuery Mobile simpledialog() clears my dynamic data from the page.
Actually I have a list, from which I am deleting record using simpledialog 
prompt. But this will clear my dynamically generated list so i have to reload 
the page to get the list back. Is there any option to get rid of this.

Below is my code:

```
$('#Delete').simpledialog({

'mode': 'bool',
'prompt': 'Are you sure to deactivate'?',
'useModal': true,
'buttons': {
    'OK': {
        click: function () {
            $('#dialogoutput').text('OK');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: deactivateUrl,
                data: { postVar: postDeactivate },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    showPageLoading("De-Activating..");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    hidePageLoading();
                    if (data = 'true') {
                        notification("Record Deactivated!");
                        location.reload();
                    }
                    else {
                        notification("Deactivation failed.");
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    //alert("Error");
                }
            });

        }
    },
    'Cancel': {
        click: function () {
            $('#dialogoutput').text('Cancel');
            location.reload();
        },
        icon: "delete",
        theme: "c"
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have,

```
if (data = 'true') {
    notification("Record Deactivated!");
    location.reload();
}
else
{
    notification("Deactivation failed.");
}
```

This:

```
if (data = 'true')
```

Will **always** be 'true' as you are setting it to 'true' with the use of a single equals.

Maybe you wanted:

```
if (data == 'true')
```

OR

```
if (data === true)
```